# Erro ao mostrar e esconder uma div com Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, html5

Senhores bom dia! Estou tentando mostrar e esconder uma imagem caso ela satisfaça as condiçoes estabelecidas, porém elas aparecem somente depois do else, não entendendo em que estou errando. Ou seja, a div cancel1, cancel2 e cancel3 não estão aparecendo quando o if é atendido.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var valor_mo_contrato_s = parseFloat($("#valor_mo_contrato").val()).toFixed(2);
    var valor_mobra_s = parseFloat($("#total_mobra_orc_calc").val()).toFixed(2);
    var valor_mat_contrato_s = parseFloat($("#valor_mat_contrato").val()).toFixed(2);
    var total_mat_orc_calc_s = parseFloat($("#total_mat_orc_calc").val()).toFixed(2);
    var valor_unitario_contrato_s = parseFloat($("#valor_unitario_contrato").val()).toFixed(2);
    var total_unitario_orc_calc_s = parseFloat($("#total_unitario_orc_calc").val()).toFixed(2);

    if (parseFloat(valor_mo_contrato_s) < parseFloat(valor_mobra_s)) {
        $("#valor_mo_orc_check").text("O Sistema sugere que o Fiscal verifique o valor de Mao de Obra.");
        $("#valor_mo_orc_check").css({"color": "red"});
        $("#cancel1").css('display','block');
    }else{
        $("#ok1").css('display','block');
    };

    if (parseFloat(valor_mat_contrato_s) < parseFloat(total_mat_orc_calc_s)) {
        $("#valor_mat_orc_check").text("O Sistema sugere que o Fiscal verifique o valor de Material.");
        $("#valor_mat_orc_check").css({"color": "red"});
        $("cancel2").css('display','block');
    }else{
        $("#ok2").css('display','block');
    };

    if (parseFloat(valor_unitario_contrato_s) < parseFloat(total_unitario_orc_calc_s)) {
        $("#valor_unitario_orc_check").text("Orcamento REPROVADO pelo SISTEMA, de acordo com os limites contratuais.");
        $("#valor_unitario_orc_check").css({"color": "red"});
        $("#cancel3").css('display','block');
    }else{
        $("#ok3").css('display','block');
    };
});
</script>
```

Comment: Além dos problemas apontados abaixo, você já confirmou que as condições dos `if`s foram verdadeiras? Um `console.log('qualquer msg')` dentro do if pode te ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No jquery voce pode usar a função `hide()` para esconder e `show()` para mostrar, tente usar isso para ver se resolve.

Comment: O problema estava na forma que eu estava tentando fazer, a div estava dentro de uma tabela, quando tirei funcionou.!

Answer (score 2):

Parece que faltou o " : " entre display e block.
Tenta assim:

```
$("#cancel1").css('display':'block');
$("#cancel2").css('display':'block');
$("#cancel3").css('display':'block');
```

*Note que no seu cancel 2 está sem o identificador '#' também gerando erro no código.

Comment: +1 pro `.show()` e `.hide()`

Comment: usei as duas formas mas sem sucesso. Fiz as modificações com as chaves e usei .hide